# Offline and online events not getting Called in cordova 3.5.0

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I am  using cordova 3.5.0 to develop my phonegap application . In that i want to check internet connectivity before web service calls . So i added network status plugin by using the command `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.network-information` . Plugin installed successfully in my application .

After Adding the plugins i added 2 EventListener's one for online and another for offline.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        console.log('App initializing...');
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        //This is to allow testing in desktop browser where there is no device ready event
        if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

        } else {
            this.onDeviceReady();
        }

    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
 onOnline:function(){
     console.log("Online");
    }.
   onOffline: function(){
     console.log("Offline");
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        require(['router'], function(Router){
            Router.getInstance();
            console.log('Backbone callback...');
        });
    }
    };
```

So i used another method to check online status as mentioned in Phonegap documentation

```
function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}
```

which is always returning the mode am connected to internet for e.g "WiFi connection" . Though i changed my disconnected my internet connection .

Help me resolving this issue .

Comment: Have you solved this? I had the same problem. I had my addEventListener functions within my App.launch() function and the app crashed and I got no events. So I put the addEventListener functions into the deviceready event and it worked..

Comment: The obove didn't solve the bug completely. This did the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790729/ios8-phonegap-cordova-network-information-app-crashes/26792735#26792735

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: the online/offline event was not firing, and sometimes when it went offline, the app crashed...

THE SOLUTION: 
  - The appropriate permission tag must bem IMMEDIATELY after the tag , in the AndroidManifest.xml file... it may appear ridiculous, but otherwise the event was not firing.

In the end, your file will look like:

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="br.com.burkard.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope.

```
document.addEventListener("offline", this.onOffline, false);
document.addEventListener("online", this.onOnline, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using the network types, as I found they do not work consistently on all platforms.

Instead I use:

```
 isOnline = function() {
    try {
    if (!navigator.onLine){
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert('An error has occurred: '+e.message);
    }
    };
```

Comment: i tried this but navigator.onLine is always undefined when i debug it. works fine in console .

Comment: That being the case are you sure you are including: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: yes my page is a single page application using backbone.js and require.js. So in my phonegap project this line included in my index.html then my require.js was loaded

Comment: You must not be accessing/including the plugin correctly then... The navigator.onLine works perfectly for me with the 3.5.0 org.apache.cordova.network-information plugin. Sorry not sure what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I would do to things.

- First add the `online` and `offline` eventlisteners only in the `onDeviceReady` function,
- Second, add scope to the `onOffline` and `onOnline` method calls in the event listeners.

Something like this:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/)) {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
} else {
    this.onDeviceReady();
}

},

onDeviceReady: function() {
    StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    document.addEventListener("offline", app.onOffline, false);
    document.addEventListener("online", app.onOnline, false);
},

onOnline:function(){
    console.log("Online");
}.
onOffline: function(){
    console.log("Offline");
},
```