# Backbone app check internet connectivity in a generic way

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, backbone.js

I am developing an phonegap  mobile application using backbone , require.js . I am doing number of ajax call for web service and  backbone model, collection fetch(), save(), destroy() in my application  . For all these web services i need to check internet connectivity in generic way .

I tried Phonegap online and offline events which are also not working . Here is my question 
[Offline and online events not getting Called in cordova 3.5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24935014/1142743)

Please guide me a generic way to find internet connectivity in my phonegap application .

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for something similar and came across this: http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/

I haven't used it, but it seems to be what you're looking for. Hope it helps!